# How do you find a question's view counter?

Tags: support, views

How do you see how many views a question has had when you're not in the <kbd>newest</kbd> category?

I've tried a word-for-word search for the question, but still can't see the view counter.

Comment: You can get live updates via comments. This question has been viewed three times today. No, six. Wait, eight. Aarg!

Comment: I can't see that where is it

Comment: I was just kidding. The real counter is in the right sidebar just below the tags, where it says "asked **today**, viewed **9 times**, active **today**"

Comment: I was gonna say

Comment: [amused] How do you *not* find the views?

Comment: hahaha Not funny

Comment: the view counter is not visible in mobile views. So not all users can see it at all timrs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the views of a question in every list — active questions, newest, your own questions in your profile, etc., but it’s not always in the same spot.

> [image: On the newest questions and tag searches, the view counter is in the bottom right corner of a question entry]

> [image: On the home page, the view counter is in the third column of a question entry]

And you can see it on the right when you open a question.

> [image: On a question page, the view counter is in the right column, on the second row]

On mobile, you can see the view counters as well. Note that you need to *Enable Responsiveness*, and use the *“full site”* rather than the old “mobile site”. You can find these links in the footer of every page. The old mobile site doesn’t show the view counter everywhere. On the newer responsive site, the view counters are almost at the same spots:

> [image: On the list of newest questions, the view counter is above the title]

On a question page, the view counter is at the bottom:

> [image: It’s below the entire answer section, in the second row]

Comment: Hmm... never seen that before

Comment: Is it possible to view the views from your profile if you have asked a question

Comment: Yes. Just open your profile and see for yourself.

Comment: can't see it anywhere

Comment: Open your profile and click on the questions tab.

Comment: Ahh... I see it now

Answer (score 3):

Every question has a views counter over to the right, listed below the time it was asked.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: ahh I see it now thanks

Comment: [Right!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F9x7W.png) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Today (in 2019), I've found the number of views on the top-right, under the blue "Ask question" button - I'm browsing this page using Chrome on a PC.

[image]

Comment: This is correct, but unfortunately it was already mentioned in the accepted answer (third screenshot).

Comment: No, the accepted answer shows the view counter under the "Post your question" blue button (at the very bottom of the page) so it's outdated because today the view counter is on the top-right corner, below the "Ask question" blue button.

Comment: What you're referring to is probably the last screenshot, which is only for small-width devices ... Please read that answer again.

Comment: Oh you are right - well that answer is so long that it's actually hard to make sense of it. So I think this answer can be useful too.